# How to start the NFT token counter with 1

Tags: solidity, nft, openzeppelin

I am writing an nft smart contract and I needed to set the first tokenId = 1, the second tokenId = 2 etc. I use the library Counters.sol (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Counters.sol). The problem is that by default _value = 0 and there is no way to change it (it gives an error).
How can I solve this problem? Any advice is important for me

Comment: Did my suggestion work out for you , buddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just invoke `tokenId.increment()` in the contract's constructor when deploying it. Like so:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

pragma solidity ^0.8.15;


contract Example  {
  using Counters for Counters.Counter;
  Counters.Counter  public tokenId;
    constructor () {
      tokenId.increment();
    }

}
```

Import it in Remix and deploy it. You will see that when you click on the `tokenId` button, it will return 1, as you want.
Hope I helped you buddy.

Comment: Good answer! Or you can also, in the minting function, call tokenId.increment just before minting the NFT so it starts minting at 1. But tomatoes tomatoes